# How to compare two files in shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file file1 and File2. I want to compare file1 with file2 and generate a file3 which contains the lines in file2 which are  present in file1.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:-

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

---

Use grep

```
$ grep -w -f file1 file2
```

- -f is used to tell grep to obtain parameters from a file.
- -w matches whole words.

**EDIT:-**

You may try this:

```
fgrep -x -f file2 -v file1
```

- -x match whole line
- -f is used to tell grep to obtain parameters from a file.
- -v inverts results

Comment: Because the patterns in `file1` will be treated as `patterns` and not plain strings and will result in lots of false positives (e.g. `bar*` in `file1` and `bar` in `file2` will match and print `bar`). Also, why `-w`?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth:- -w so that it matches the whole word! Am I missing something?

Comment: Which word(s)? OP didn't say anything about words but maybe I am missing something. But as I explained above, this is the wrong approach in the first place.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth:- `file3 which contains the lines in file2` So I assumed that line will consist of words and thats why given this answer!

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth:- You may edit my answer if you have a better idea or answer to it! :)

Comment: Ah now I see, you copied @fedorqui's answer from the linked duplicate. For the other question this worked, but for generic lines it doesn't.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth:- This is not a copied answer. But yes it looks similar. I have provided the explanation which is not there in that answer!

Comment: Fair enough, it's still an incorrect answer to this question :)

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth:- Updated my answer. Hope that works! :)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I explained why you cannot use `grep`. You don't want anything in those files to be treated like patterns/regular expressions or you might get false positives (even with `-x`, but the idea was good).

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth:- Then do it through awk, `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($0 in a)' file2 file1`

Comment: Better, but I think you meant `($0 in a)`? :)

Comment: You should replace your answer with that then :)